# Get search result of google in java

Tags: java, search

I got 403 response code in this program, but I need to get 200 to getting back the search result, what can I do?

```
      String url="http://www.google.com/search?q=";
      String charset="UTF-8";
      String key="java";
      String query = String.format("%s",URLEncoder.encode(key, charset));
      URLConnection con = new URL(url+ query).openConnection();
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
      System.out.println(inputLine);
      in.close();
```

Comment: use the sdk... http://code.google.com/p/google-search-java-sdk/

Comment: Not related to your problem, but what do you think `String.format("%s", ... )` is doing for you?

Comment: it put key in %s format with charset UTF-8 i think

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what that means; and I think you don't either.

Comment: Go sniff an actual HTTP request from your browser. You'll se a handful of request headers in there and some are probably essential to google letting you in.

Comment: my response code is 403,but i need it 200 to getting bck search result,what is my program problem?

Comment: Even if you use the same headers as a browser does, you'll end up getting a 302 redirect to `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: My code updated and works, try it

Comment: Why would anyone help you circumvent Google's terms of service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is blocking the default UserAgent sent by Java. You can use another one and trick Google. Simply add:

`con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");`

after creating the con and before starting to read.

Answer (score 4):

Try with [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

```
Document document = Jsoup
        .connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0")     
        .get();

System.out.println(document.html());
```

For extracting links use [selector api](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how? where i have to use this

Comment: @MariuszS I love Jsoup, too ;-) . But the problem of the request signature remains

Answer (score 3):

[403 response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is clear enough. Google servers tells you the way you're doing things is not a way that is authorized, nor tolerated.

[Google prohibits the use of automated queries](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en) and using it is at your own risk of being blocked at any time.

If you want to go down this road, you'll have to understand why you are blocked (User-agent, IP adress, Header fingerprinting, etc. There are a lot of means for them to know if you're a bot or not)

Comment: i think is simply easier than i thaught

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to JSoup, you can use this [package](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-java).

Code sample:

```
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();
parameter.put("q", "Coffee");
parameter.put("location", "Portland");
GoogleSearchResults serp = new GoogleSearchResults(parameter);

JsonObject data = serp.getJson();
JsonArray results = (JsonArray) data.get("organic_results");
JsonObject first_result = results.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println("first coffee: " + first_result.get("title").getAsString());
```