# Java Return a List of Google URL Results without Custom Search API?

Tags: java, api, search

I need to be able to get thousands of results a day, and the Custom Search API only allows 100. Is there any way to remove this limit or get results without the use of their API? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that needs to know this (I got it now!):

Get the source using the JSoup library:

```
Document document = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0")     
    .get();

System.out.println(document.html());
```

Then you can parse the URLs from inside the A (href) tags! Voila!

**Credit to Grooveek here:** [Get search result of google in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758824/get-search-result-of-google-in-java)